# Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Currently the `VariableService` is `@Autowired` in my controller.

I realize I can implement  the class `ParameterizedType` to make this error go away but I fear that I may be headed in the wrong direction.  Is there a better way to do this or do I need to bite the bullet and implement `ParameterizedType`'s methods?

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.fettergroup.cmt.service.VariableService com.fettergroup.cmt.web.ContentController.variableService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'variableService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.fettergroup.cmt.service.VariableService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: **java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType**

**Variable Service**

```
public class VariableService extends EntityService {
    public VariableService () {
        super.setEntityRepository(new VariableRepository());
    }
}
```

**EntityService**

```
public abstract class EntityService<T> {

    public EntityRepository<T> entityRepository;

    public T create(T entity) {
        return entityRepository.create(entity);
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        return entityRepository.update(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        entityRepository.delete(entity);
    }

    public void setEntityRepository(EntityRepository<T> entityRepository) {
        this.entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }
}
```

**Variable Repository**

```
public class VariableRepository extends EntityRepository {

}
```

**EntityRepository**

```
@Repository
public abstract class EntityRepository<T> {

    //the equivalent of User.class
    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(type= PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityRepository () {
        //Get "T" and assign it to this.entityClass
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    /**
     * Create this entity
     * @param t
     * @return 
     */
    public T create(T t) {
        entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Update this entity
     * @param t
     * @return 
     */
    public T update(T t) {
        return entityManager.merge(t);
    }

    /**
     * Delete this entity
     * @param entity 
     */
    public void delete(T t) {
        t = this.update(t);
        entityManager.remove(t);
    }

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just saying, this is a pretty poor design for determining the entity type..
You should do the following instead of relying on reflection to infer its class def..
Not only will it get rid of that error, but it will be overall cleaner and at a low level, faster than reflection (not that it would really be an issue).

```
@Repository
public abstract class EntityRepository<T>{
    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    public EntityRepository(Class<T> entityClass){
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    //...
}


public class UserEntityRepository extends EntityRepository<User>{
    public UserEntityRepository(){
        super(User.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to say that this is the design approach i use for my data access layer. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: can spring autowire the entityClass this way?

Answer (score 11):

EntityRepository isn't ParameterizedType type. This class only extends ParameterizedType. This is also possible if spring proxied you class by cglib

We need check parents of class

```
public EntityRepository () {
    //Get "T" and assign it to this.entityClass
    Type genericSuperClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

    ParameterizedType parametrizedType = null;
    while (parametrizedType == null) {
        if ((genericSuperClass instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperClass;
        } else {
            genericSuperClass = ((Class<?>) genericSuperClass).getGenericSuperclass();
        }
    }

    entityClass = (Class<T>) parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are misusing `ParameterizedType`.
In the `EntityRepository` constructor, you should be using something like the following, with the appropriate checks.

```
public EntityRepository () {
    //Get "T" and assign it to this.entityClass
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Type type = genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if (type instanceof Class) {
      this.entityClass = (Class<T>) type;
    } else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      this.entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)type).getRawType();
    }
}
```

This implementation is far from complete though, as you should also handle `GenericArrayType` values, as well as nested `ParameterizedType`.

Comment: I added your content and imported `java.lang.reflect.Type;` and `type` does not have the method `getRawType()`

Comment: oh, i forgot a cast. It `type` is of type `ParameterizedType`, you have to cast it to `ParameterizedType` in order to call `getRawType()`.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, adding pro guard rules solved the issue, because I was using the Type wrapped in Live Data.

But the issue failed to replicate in a new project. Possible that there were issues with multiple modules in the project.

Rule added:

```
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.LiveData { *; }
```

Here is the thread to solution :
[ClassCastException java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/1088)

If you have recently upgraded Gradle and Java in your project, you are most likely using R8. So you might wanna check out the other dependencies for your project to work, like :

[GSON Proguard for R8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61481954/14784590)

[Retrofit Proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65251059/14784590)

Answer (score 1):

@Repository annotation needs to be removed from the class EntityRepository to solve the problem.

Read this thread

[java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067512/java-lang-class-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-reflect-parameterizedtype/42887896#42887896)