# java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

Tags: java, spring

I am stuck with this issue for a long time. I searched for this issue for sometime but none of solution worked.

Structure:

```
public interface GenericDAO<T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable>

@Repository
public class AbstractGenericDAO<T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> 
    implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

   private Class<T> persistentClass;

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AbstractGenericDAO.class);


   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public AbstractGenericDAO() {
       this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
   }

   /**
    * @param entity
    * @return T
    * @throws DBException
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public T saveEntity(T entity) throws DBException {
       return saveEntity(entity, false);
   }

   /**
    * @param entity
    * @param explicitFlush
    * @return T
    * @throws DBException
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public T saveEntity(T entity, boolean explicitFlush) throws DBException {
       Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

       try {
           session.save(entity);
           if(explicitFlush) {
               session.flush();
               session.refresh(entity);
           }
       } catch (HibernateException he) {
           String errorMsg = "Could not save entity. Reason: " + he.getMessage();
           LOGGER.error(errorMsg, he);
           throw new DBException(errorMsg, he);
       }

       return entity;
   }

   /* (non-Javadoc)
    * @see com.amazon.fc.receive.dbaccess.dao.GenericDAO#getPersistentClass()
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
       return persistentClass;
   }

   /**
    * @return the sessionFactory
    */
   public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
       return this.sessionFactory;
   }

   /**
    * @param sessionFactory the sessionFactory to set
    */
   @Autowired
   public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
   }
}

public interface ShlkActiveWorkflowDAO 
    extends GenericDAO<ShlkActiveWorkflow, Serializable> 

@Repository
public class ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl 
    extends AbstractGenericDAO<ShlkActiveWorkflow, Serializable>
    implements ShlkActiveWorkflowDAO
```

I am also using `<context:component-scan>` in my `application-config.xml`
    `+ <tx:annotation-driven />` in my `application-config.xml`.

Please provide some information about how to fix this issue.

```
Exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abstractGenericDAO' 

Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:890)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at com.coral.spring.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:95)
    at com.coral.spring.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:56)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.workflow.dao.AbstractGenericDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is     
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:938)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
    at com.workflow.dao.AbstractGenericDAO.<init>(AbstractGenericDAO.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: We need more code from the class **com.workflow.dao.AbstractGenericDAO**

Comment: Do you really need `AbstractGenericDAO` to be annotated with `@Repository`? From your architecture it looks like it only makes sense to inject the more specialized type. Remember that every [Repository](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) is by definition a `@Component` which can be wired.

Comment: I just addded some code for AbstractGenericDAO.java

Comment: so should I use @Component instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove `@Repository` annotation from `AbstractGenericDAO` and make it `abstract`:

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericDAO<T extends Serializable, ID extends Serializable> 
   implements GenericDAO<T, ID>
```

Your problem occurs because `@Repository` is a specialization of `@Component`, which means that Spring will try to create `AbstractGenericDAO` instances for injection. Since `AbstractGenericDAO` superclass (`Object`) is not generic, you will not be able to downcast its `Type` to `ParameterizedType`, and so this line of code will fail (in the same way that it would if you tried to instantiate it manually with `new AbstractGenericDAO()`):

```
this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

The specialized class `ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl` should still be annotated with `@Repository`. When spring tries to create a instance of this class a implicit call to `AbstractGenericDAO` constructor will occur, but this time the line of code mentioned above will run as expected. This happens because `getClass()` returns `ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl.class` which is a subclass of the generic `AbstractGenericDAO` (so the downcast to `ParameterizedType` works).

Since `ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl` `extends` `AbstractGenericDAO<ShlkActiveWorkflow, Serializable>` the actual type `ShlkActiveWorkflow` will be correctly reflected at runtime. This is a known workaround to avoid passing a `Class<T>` reference to the `AbstractGenericDAO` constructor.

If you are worried about the `@Autowired` annotation at `AbstractGenericDAO`, don't be. Spring will correctly wire everything up when you inject a instance of one of its subclasses.

Comment: Thanks. This working fine but when I added one more annotation inside ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl, then I am getting the same exception.

Comment: I have added internal annotation '@Timed' inside one of the methods of ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl

Comment: I think you should open a new topic for this error. Anyway, you should not use `@Timed` and other testing annotations in your development layer. Create a separate [testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html#unit-testing) layer and inject your object (or a mock).

Comment: I will open a separate topic for this. But '@Timed' is not for testing. This is our annotation for metrics.

Comment: I thought that you were referring to [org.springframework.test.annotation.Timed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Timed.html) which is specific for testing.

Comment: But if you are getting the same exception, the problem seems to be that your custom annotation, for some reason, is trying to construct a Instance of `AbstractGenericDAO`... Try creating another component (Ex. ShlkActiveWorkflowMeasures), injecting a instance of `ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl` with @Autowired, and have one of this new component methods annotated with `@Timed`. If it works you can always make that method delegate to the ShlkActiveWorkflowDAOImpl method that you want to measure.

Comment: That worked. I will create a ShlkDataAccessManager and redirect all the DAO calls from there. I can also use '@Timed' annotation there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Type genericSuperClass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();

ParameterizedType parametrizedType = null;
while (parametrizedType == null) {
   if ((genericSuperClass instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
       parametrizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperClass;
   } else {
       genericSuperClass = ((Class<?>) genericSuperClass).getGenericSuperclass();
   }
}

this.itemClass = (Class<T>) parametrizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Comment: why negative score?

It is possible that spring proxied class AbstractGenericDAO by cglib, so we need check hierarchy