# Extend class from another extended Parametrized Generic class

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a genericService support classes ( genericService, GenericServiceImpl, GenericDao,GenericHibernateDao) for generic service,dao layer.

Normaly it works fine, When i extend any type parametrized service from abstract generic services.When i extend this extended services in different service it gives:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

error.

My GEnericHibernateDao:

@Transactional
public abstract class GenericHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDaoTemplate
{
    private Class type;

```
public GenericHibernateDaoSupport() {
    this.type =  (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier(value = "productSessionFactory")
 public void bindSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}

public Class<T> getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(Class<T> type) {
    this.type = type;
}

protected Session getCurrentSession() {
    return getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
}

public ID persist(T newInstance) {
    return (ID) getHibernateTemplate().save(newInstance);
}

public void update(T transientObject) {
    getHibernateTemplate().update(transientObject);
}
```

Here is my standart extended HibernateDao class:

```
@Repository
public class StandadHibernateDao extends standardHibernateDaoSupport<Standard, Long> implements StandardDao {
```

Above extend operation works fine, But when i tried something like this:

```
@Repository
public class ExtendStandardGatewayHibernateDao extends StandadHibernateDao implements ExtendedStandardDao {
```

it throws :

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067512/java-lang-class-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-reflect-parameterizedtype this link helps maybe