# Google playstore gson serialize difers from gson serialize from local install

Tags: android, gson

I have this class

```
public class _CtV3 {
    private long   _ct_id;
    private String _ct_eml;
    private int    _ct_lst;
    private int    _ct_til;
    private String _ct_gid;
    private int    _ct_ntr;
    private int    _ct_nle;
    private int    _ct_nlm;
    private String _ct_uui;

    public _CtV3(long ct_id, String ct_eml, int ct_lst, int ct_til, String ct_gid, int ct_ntr, int ct_nle, int ct_nlm, String ct_uui) {
        this._ct_id  = ct_id;
        this._ct_eml = ct_eml;
        this._ct_lst = ct_lst;
        this._ct_til = ct_til;
        this._ct_gid = ct_gid;
        this._ct_ntr = ct_ntr;
        this._ct_nle = ct_nle;
        this._ct_nlm = ct_nlm;
        this._ct_uui = ct_uui;
    }
    ...
}
```

which at some point is serialized with Gson with...

```
 String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
 ctV3 = new _CtV3(0, "", 0, 0, "", 0, -1, 0, uuid);

 GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
 Gson gson = builder.create();
 String dec = gson.toJson(ctV3);

 Log.d(TAG, dec);
```

Now the problem. If I install on an android phone directly from Android Studio everything works fine and Log returns

```
{"_ct_eml":"","_ct_gid":"","_ct_id":0,"_ct_lst":0,"_ct_nle":-1,"_ct_nlm":0,"_ct_ntr":0,"_ct_til":0,"_ct_uui":"f0438604-a22b-44d3-bb4b-9303a828b0f9"}
```

If I install on the same phone from Google PlayStore the same Log returns

```
{"a":0,"b":"","c":0,"d":0,"e":0,"f":-1,"g":0,"h":"19ff09be-07d1-411d-a625-bcf4b574abec"}
```

This issue came up last month as my last upgrade took place in early September.

Comment: is proguard enabled for your app ?

Comment: @Swayangjit Yes, it is. I think you got it.

Comment: Not proguard but "minifyEnabled = true;" that I enabled almost without thinking about the consequences.

Comment: Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826171/proguard-for-android-and-gson) and apply it in your progurad-rules.pro file.