# Android Singed APK crashed

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am facing issue with the Signed APK, debug apk works perfectly, When I generate signed apk and run it show error.

below is error log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.woodenstreet, PID: 25818
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method x(Ljava/lang/String;I)I in class Lorg/json/JSONObject; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.json.JSONObject' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.DefaultSettingsJsonTransform.d(SourceFile:1)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.DefaultSettingsJsonTransform.e(SourceFile:2)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController.(SourceFile:11)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.SettingsController.l(SourceFile:14)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.l(SourceFile:4)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.FirebaseCrashlytics.a(SourceFile:26)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.b(SourceFile:5)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar.a(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar$$Lambda$1.a(Unknown Source:2)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.f(SourceFile:1)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4)
> at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(SourceFile:6)
> at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.e(SourceFile:5)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.n(SourceFile:7)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.q(SourceFile:13)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.p(SourceFile:1)
> at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.o(SourceFile:7)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:1)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2092)
> at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2066)
> at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:2)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6983)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Here build.gradle app level file

[Build file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MpEEOTKNunr2u9F4DxgIcy94p4coKgz6EAunuub5PvE/edit?usp=sharing)

I am not able to figure out the error please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your release configuration in build.gradle is not correct for your libraries. I think it have to do with json, and proguard obfuscates some methods of it.
try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61481954/10117882