# Gson and Ktor production build converts json names to letters

Tags: android, gson, ktor

I use Gson to create a Json string when sending data from my Android app back to the server using Ktor.

Works fine for debug release, but under release Gson appears to convert all the member names to letters

How it should look:
[image]

How it looks on release compile:
[image]

This must be a configuration to set somewhere?  How do I force Gson to retain variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Release build minification obfuscates names, including your model class fields. Some options:

1. You can add gson's `@SerializedName("field")` annotations to your model class fields to specify the JSON names to be used with those fields despite obfuscation.
2. You can add `-keep` rules to your R8/Proguard configuration file to prevent your model classes from being obfuscated.

Comment: Can you point me at the -keep rules I should use, I would prefer this approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62133361/101361

Comment: Unfortunately setting -keep rules didn't work.  This issue is compounded by the need to build a release version and deploy it before I can check if a fix has worked, feels like poor Gson code to me...

Comment: I had to set the @SerializeName on each membername that I wanted to keep AND then added `-keepclassmembers class * {
      @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
    }` to the pro-guard rules