# Which ProGuard Rules are need for using GSON with Google Maps?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

This started after upgrading my Gradle.
Creating test builds of my app works fine.
It's when I create a Release Build that my app crashes with the following error message:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.richmondgamesstudio.foraging, PID: 22275 
**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.l cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng**
 at  com.richmondgamesstudio.foraging.Helper.l.b(Unknown Source:37) 
at
y2.d.f(Unknown Source:448) at s2.b.onTransact(Unknown Source:89) 
at  android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1164) 
at  fc.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014047@22.50.14 (190800-0):2) 
at  com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014047@22.50.14 (190800-0):1) 
at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at  android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

If I comment out **minifyEnabled** and **shrinkResources** in the gradle.build file. Then my release build works just fine. I suspect I need to add something to my proguard-rules

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken


##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following line to my proguard file fixed my issue

```
-keep class com.yourpackage.datatypes.* { <fields>; }
```

This post helped me: [ProGuard for Android and GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826171/proguard-for-android-and-gson)