# Proguard rules for retrofit android

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am implementing proguard rules to the android app. when I am compiling that apk, still retrofit classes are not changing. Please have a look at my proguard file and Please guide me where I am missing the rules.

```
-keep public class org.slf4j.** { *; }
-keep public class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep public class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class com.ibm.hrl.datacapArfl.ArActivity { *; }
-keep class com.ibm.ecm.capture.** { *; }
-keep class com.googlecode.tesseract.android.** { *; }
-keep class com.fiberlink.** { *; }
-keep class com.ibm.androidsampleapplication.model.**{*;}

-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }

-keep class com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn org.apache.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.ning.http.**
-dontwarn ch.qos.logback.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.impl.auth.**
-dontwarn com.fiberlink.maas360sdk.**
-dontwarn com.fiberlink.maas360.**
-dontwarn com.ibm.ecm.navigator.mdm.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.**
-dontwarn javax.**
-dontwarn lombok.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn com.sun.**
-dontwarn **retrofit**
-dontwarn **okio**
-dontwarn com.ibm.**

-dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
#-keep class resources.**{*;}
#-keep class sources.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
    }
```

Comment: Please add details as to what your problem is and what errors you are encountering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find recommended retrofit proguard rules here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/retrofit2.pro